# High resolution and Java Apps

Tags: graphics, ati, 9.10, java

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 with an Ati Radeon X1300 pro, resolution 1600x1050. 
The problem is about slow speed when I use java apps. 
For instance, NetBeans is unusable cause of lack of speed.

With others app (non java) the problem doesn't appear.

So my question is if this can be a Java problem or a video card (+ driver) problem?

Comment: Which Java Virtual Machine are you using? Sun or OpenJDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say exactly what is wrong but I can point you in some direction. I (as well as some otrher people) have had problems because of bad Xorg configuration. Look at [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=70722) example to give you some clue.